# Wildcard or equivalent to read in excel file

Tags: regex, excel, import, wildcard

I have multiple excel files imported on a daily basis, example code of one of the files is here:

Booked <- read_excel("./Source_Data/CONFIDENTIAL - MI8455 Future Change 20180717.xlsx", skip = 1, sheet = "Appendix 1 - Info Data")

Each day this file changes, the name and structure is always the same, the only difference is the date at the end of the file name.

Is there anyway to have R search for the specific name starting with "CONFIDENTIAL - MI8455 Future Change" and import the data accordingly?

Comment: Still a bit stuck, I have worked out how to get a list of files. But cannot work out how to then get the files to be picked up in the order that I need in terms of specific sheets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, through a lot of trial, error and google I found an answer and hope that someone else who is new to R may have come across the same problem.

First I needed to identify the file, in the end I used the list.files command:  `MI8455 <- list.files(path= "G:/MY/FilE/PATH/MI8455", pattern="^MI8455_Rate_Change_Report_1.*\\.xlsx$")` If likemyself your files are either in other folders/subfolders of the working directory than the first part of the code specifies where the list.files should look. The pattern element allows you to show what format the name is in and then you are able to specify the file type.

Next you can import using the read_excel package, but rather than specifiying a file path you tell it to use the value that you created earlier: `Customer_2017 <- read_excel(MI8455,skip = 5, sheet = "Case Listing - Eml")`

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of the file out you can use this pattern

```
(?'path'\.\/Source_Data\/CONFIDENTIAL - MI8455 Future Change \d+\.xlsx)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, you'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge, I've only been using R for a week and am teaching myself.

I can't seem to get the syntax working with the rest of the command, so how to find file, and read the specific sheet only in as an excel file.